Do I need declare as volatile the supplier class member in order to preserve thread-safety
I am reading this book "Functional Programming in Java Harnessing the Power Of Java 8 Lambda Expressions" and in chapter 6 (lazy evaluations) there's an example of heavy object creation. Basically the example looks like this:
public class HeavyObjectCreation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeavyObjectCreation h = new HeavyObjectCreation();
        h.getHeavy();
        h.getHeavy();
        h.getHeavy();
    }

    public static class Heavy {}
    private Supplier<Heavy> heavy = this::createAndCacheHeavy;
    public HeavyObjectCreation() {

    }
    public Heavy getHeavy() {
        System.out.println("Getting heavy");
        return heavy.get();
    }
    private synchronized Heavy createAndCacheHeavy() {
        class HeavyFactory implements Supplier<Heavy> {
            private final Heavy heavyInstance = new Heavy();
            public Heavy get() { return heavyInstance; }
        }

        System.out.println("bypassing");

        if(!(heavy instanceof HeavyFactory)) {
            System.out.println("Creating heavy");
            heavy = new HeavyFactory();
        }
        return heavy.get();
    }
}

I was thinking whether I should declare "heavy" class member as volatile since it is accessed in two places: createAndCacheHeavy() which is synchronized and getHeavy() which is not synchronized. So my assumption is that there is no happens-before relationship between writing of "heavy" reference and reading it and that is why I think it should be declared as volatile:
private volatile Supplier heavy = ...
I would appreciate any help. Thanks!
P.S getHeavy() is invoked by other threads.

This is an intentional racy access. In your example, there are no other threads but if getHeavy() is invoked by other threads, it’s possible that they see an old value, which poses no problem, as then, they will enter the synchronized method which re-checks. It’s also possible that they see the new value through a data race, in other words, there is indeed no happens-before relationship to the write in this case, but then, they’re reading Heavy through the final field heavyInstance, which provides additional “safe initialization” guarantees.

Kind of irrelevant because what you are doing is not idiomatic java at all. Here's the idiomatic version: https://ideone.com/wSluPN

See JLS, §17.5. final Field Semantics

@Michael except that your “idiomatic version” is completely broken.
